# Read data from different system in different format, like xml, csv, database, etc in IBM BPM

Tags: web-services, soa, ibm-bpm

I am very new to IBM BPM. I want to know how can i read/write data from/to different system to IBM BPM ? What are the different formats supported ? like xml, csv, database, WSDL etc.  ??

Let us suppose I have a system from where i can get some data, may be in the form of xml, csv or database, etc (without WSDL contract. Now I want to create an interface in my IBM BPM, which can be used to read/extract data from  above mentioned system. Is this possible without a WSDL contract ?

Comment: You can write custom Java integration to work with ever you want... most of the ones you need are already included in the platform.  Also, xml and csv are not systems they are formats for data.  If you want to import data into BPM from XML it has a built in parser.  If you want to parse CSV I think you'll have to write your own... but not sure.

Answer (score 2):

IBM BPM provides out of the box connectors for both the standard (BPMN) and advanced (BPEL) products. For BPM Standard the [System Data Toolkit](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFPJS_8.5.5/com.ibm.wbpm.admin.doc/topics/managing_toolkits_A.html?lang=en) has built in ready to go integration points for databases, SOAP, XML parsing, HTTP requests, and more. There are a few examples of connectors in the [L2-SampleApps project](https://hub.jazz.net/project/mfilley/bpm-L2SampleApps/overview). There are more here on the [BPM Tutorials page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/bpcsamp/v7r5) and [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/integration/business-process-manager/library/documentation/tutorials.html). and a [full PDF](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/integration/business-process-manager/library/documentation/tutorials.html) of simple how to samples.

For the advanced side, there are [some example here](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/bpcsamp/v6r2/) which have code you can review for connecting to various outside systems.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "import from a remote location" which of the following do you mean

A user looking at a coach and uploading to the server from their computer
A user lookking at a coach and uploading to the server from a network location
A user looking at a coach and selecting from a location on the BPM server
The server accessing a file on its file system
The server accessing a file on another file system

If it is one of the coach options, you could use the file upload widget for coaches and then parse the file that is uploaded from the file repository using one of the open source java packages that allow reading of excel spreadsheets.

You can get this information here:

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014873642